# Writing to postgreSQL database

Tags: python, postgresql, point

I'm trying to create a point geometry from a lat, lon pair read from a json, and then write to a database table in postgreSQL that has already been created with the appropriate variable types. I don't think there's anything wrong with my code but it will not write to database.  When I use the command line in pgadmin and put numbers in, it works fine.  What am I doing wrong? Relevant code below:

```
        points=item['points']
        trip_id = int(trip_ID)

        for point in points:
            lat = float(point['lat'])
            lon = float(point['lng'])
            dist = float(point['dis'])
            elev = float(point['ele'])

            try:
                conn = psycopg2.connect(host=PG_HOST, port=PG_PORT, dbname=PG_DBNAME, user=PG_USER, password=PG_PASS)
                cur = conn.cursor()
                sql ='INSERT INTO mmf_2d (trip_id, dist, elev, geom) values(%s, %s, %s, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(%s, %s), 4326))'
                cur.execute(sql, (trip_id, dist, elev, lon, lat ))
                conn.commit()
            except:
                print('Save to DB failed!')
                break
```

Resolution: make parameters in cur.execute string and no spaces after %s, thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: If, instead of the code inside your `except` block, you write `raise`, what do you get? i.e., what is the particular exception you are getting. This is relevant because it could be any issue at all, including one about permissions. There isn't enough here to diagnose.

Comment: db connection needs quotes > https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_python.htm but post your error will give more detailed clues.

Comment: Parameter wildcards in the SQL string need to be of type `string`, i.e. `%s`!

Comment: I tried changing parameters to string and it's still not working.  Excuse my ignorance since I'm really new to coding, I was trying to find the syntax to raise an exception as suggested, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I added:       except(Exception) as e:
                    print(e)
                    print(type(e))
                    break                                                    it showed: <class 'ValueError'>
unsupported format character ',' (0x2c) at index 55.  Turns out, there cannot be a space after my %s,!  Thanks everyone!

Comment: FYI, you don't need to set the infos within your script with environment variables. See my comment on this psycopg2 recipe https://gist.github.com/jayu108/bebd10b5b1648aab0531#gistcomment-3191811